# TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer when opening a file

Tags: python

i have the next code

```
import requests, os, sys
from colorama import *
foo = f"{Fore.GREEN}[+] {Fore.WHITE}"
def subhyp():
    try:
        kukipbcxz = open('lala.txt','a')
        rp = requests.get("example.com")
        jui = str(rp.text)
        print(jui, file = a)
        print(f"\n{foo}Results saved in lala.txt")
        a.close()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

print("""
1.- someoption1
2.- someoption2
3.- sometestoption3
""")

a = str(input("Option = "))
if a == "1":
   print("someoption1")
elif a == "2":
   print("someoption2")
elif a == "3":
   subhyp()
```

When i Execute Code and select sometestoption3 i get the following error in terminal

```
    a = open("lala.txt",'w')
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I have tried convert (a) into str with the next code and i got the next output on terminal
a = open(str("lala.txt",'w'))
Output:

```
    a = open(str("lala.txt",'w'))
TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

i dont know why this happening if someone can provide me a solution i would appreciate it, thanks for read :)

Comment: i have tried this

    a = open(str("lala.txt"),'w')
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

and dont working too

Comment: Please show the full traceback, not just the last line.

Comment: You have somehow overwritten the standard `open()` function with something different - perhaps the version of `open` in the `os` module, which takes an integer rather than a string as the second parameter.  The obvious culprit is `from colorama import *`; you have *no idea* what all was brought into your namespace by this wildcard import.  Either import only the specific names you need, or do `import colorama` and then use `colorama.Fore`, etc.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por mi\prueba.py", line 27, in <module>
    subhyp()
  File "X:\scripts de python por mi\Scripts por m\prueba.py", line 6, in subhyp
    a = open(str("lala.txt"),'w'))
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My crystal ball says that `from colorama import *` (or maybe another import you're not showing us) accidentally overwrites the built-in `open` with `os.open`, which would indeed give the error you're quoting.

```
>>> from os import open
>>> open("foo.txt", "a")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>>>
```

Additionally, you're opening the file with the (nonsense) variable name `kukipbcxz`, but you'd be using `file=a`, so that won't work either. (Your IDE should highlight `kukipbcxz` being unused, and `a` not being assigned. If it doesn't, switch IDEs...)

It's also better to use `with` with files, so all in all, try:

```
import requests
from colorama import Fore

foo = f"{Fore.GREEN}[+] {Fore.WHITE}"


def subhyp():
    try:
        rp = requests.get("example.com")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return
    with open('lala.txt', 'a') as a:
        jui = str(rp.text)
        print(jui, file=a)
        print(f"\n{foo}Results saved in lala.txt")


print("""
1.- someoption1
2.- someoption2
3.- sometestoption3
""")

a = str(input("Option = "))
if a == "1":
    print("someoption1")
elif a == "2":
    print("someoption2")
elif a == "3":
    subhyp()
```